# How can I request a POST to the django rest framework except for null json?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making an api with the django rest framework. Now, in my api, where I don't want the content to go in, I'm sending a request: "field": null. But I want to send a request without specifying this field in json, how should I handle it? Here's my code.

```
class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    owner = userProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    like_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    images = ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    liked_people = LikeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    tag = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), allow_null=True)

    #If I don't want to get a tag, I want to erase the tag field altogether instead of "tag": null.

    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'content', 'view_count', 'images', 'like_count', 'comment_count', 'liked_people', 'tag', 'created_at', 'comments')
```

Comment: Remove the **`tag`** field from `Meta.fields`

Comment: try setting required = False https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required

Comment: I don't always have to get tag but sometimes I have to and sometimes I don't. Is the method appropriate in this case?

Comment: I was able to solve it through required=False. Thank you!